# How to keep track the amount of even integers when looking through randomized list using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Sorta newbie here. So in trying to wrap my head around using recursive functions I wanted to try to make a program that:

1: Generates a list containing 10 random integers ranging from 0 - 20

2: Using a recursive function goes trough the list and finds out what elements of the list are **even integers**

3: Prints out **only** the aformentioned **even** numbers

Where I have gotten stuck is in how to print out the result. I can't seem to figure out what value i want to put inside the function when calling it ( F(?) )

I tried to integrate a counter that kept track on how many times the program found a even number but it always resulted in an error that the variable is not defined no matter how hard I tried to make it global.

How could I go about this? Am I totally in the wrong?

```
import random
numL = []
for i in range(10):
    x = random.randint(0,20)
    numL.append(x)

print(numL)

def F(x):
    if numL[x] % 2 == 0:
        return numL[x]
    else:
        return F(x+1)

print(F( ??? ))
```

First question asked on this forum, hopefully I did okay, appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to return a list of the even numbers then you have 4 cases to consider

1. This is the last number in the list and its even so return this number
2. This is the last number in the list and its odd dont retrun this number
3. There are more numbers to check and this number is even so return
   this plus the function result
4. There are more numbers to check and this number is odd to return
   only the function result  and not this num

So we can code this as

```py
import random

def get_even_nums(nums):
    num = nums[0]
    #This is our terminating case we definitivly return a value here
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return [num] if num % 2 == 0 else []
    else:
        #If we got here we will be recursivly calling the function
        #If its even number return that number plus the result of the function
        #it its not even then just return the reult of the function and not this num
        if num % 2 == 0:
            return [num] + get_even_nums(nums[1:])
        else:
            return get_even_nums(nums[1:])


numL = [random.randint(0, 20) for _ in range(10)]
print(numL)
print(get_even_nums(numL))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[3, 6, 5, 10, 20, 18, 5, 0, 3, 9]
[6, 10, 20, 18, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

So I took your function and changed it up slightly (using a slightly different approach). There's no need to a global list, though you could do that as well, if you wanted. The problem that you have is the lack of a `base case` or rather an incorrect one.

If you run your original function with an argument `0`, which basically is the first element of your generated array, the fucntion will run until it hits one even number. At that point it'll exit recursion, because the base case basically stops recursive calls once you hit an even number.

Now, to fix this, you have to approach the problem differently. I would put your generated array as the input argument to your function, then ask myself "What would be a good base case?" Probably one that stops your recursive calls once you reach the end of the input list.

```
if len(numL) == 0:
    return ...
```

Also, we need a way to return the even numbers that we found during our search through the list. For that reason I'd introduce a new `acc` list, where we would append the even numbers that we found. Thus the function input arguments would be

```
def F(numL, acc):
    ...
```

Now, in the recursive call we should check wether the current element is even or not. If it is, great, we add it to the `acc` list and continue into the recursive call. If it's not, we don't add anything to the `acc` but just continue with recursion.

```
if numL[0] % 2 == 0:
    acc.append(numL[0])
    return F(numL[1:], acc)
```

Putting it all together, we get:

```
def F(numL, acc):
    if len(numL) == 0:
        return  acc
    else:
        if numL[0] % 2 == 0:
            acc.append(numL[0])
        return F(numL[1:], acc)
```

where `numL` represents your generated list and `acc` represents the resulting list we'll return after we traverse the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is your function (as I understand it, you wanted this):

```
import random

def F(i):
    r = random.randint(0,20)
    if r % 2 == 0:
        print(r)
    i += 1
    if i != 10:
        F(i)

F(0)
```